# Prove that a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ which is periodic attains its extreme values.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, periodic-functions

> Prove that a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ which is periodic attains its extreme values.

I don't know how to start this proof, but I know I have to use the extreme value theorem, continuity and something with compact sets.

Comment: First prove it on some compact interval of length $\ge$ to the period.

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function with period $T$, then the image of $f$ is realized in any closed interval of length $T$.

Comment: I have written, let $f$: p $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the period equals $p$ and use the fact that the function attains all its values on, e.g., $[0,p]$, which is compact.